# How to convert a list of objects with int, string properties to list of objects with all string properties

Tags: c#, string, int

How to convert a list of objects with int, string properties to list of objects with all string properties?

For example: I have a list of objects with multi type of property likes  `{ int Cd, string Name}`

I want to convert to list of objects which all string properties likes `{string Cd, string Cd}`

Comment: Use linq: `list.select(item => new { item.cd.ToString(), item.Name, }` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `Select` like @MichaWiedenmann suggested and create a new anonymous class with `Cd` and `Name` properties. The `x.Cd.ToString()` part is converting the integer property `Cd` of every object inside `list` to a string:

```
List<myObject> list = new List<myObject>()
{
     new myObject() {Cd=1,Name="John" },
     new myObject() {Cd=2,Name="Peter" },
     new myObject() {Cd=3,Name="David" }
};

var newList = list.Select(x => new { Cd = x.Cd.ToString(), Name = x.Name }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use following reflection approach.

This is a class which holds all relevant properties and fields and their values:

```
public class StringType
{
    public StringType(IDictionary<MemberInfo, string> allPropertiesAndFields)
    {
        this.PropertiesAndFields = allPropertiesAndFields;
        this.PropertyFieldNamesAndValues = allPropertiesAndFields.ToDictionary(m => m.Key.Name, m => m.Value);
    }

    private IDictionary<MemberInfo, string> PropertiesAndFields { get; set; }
    private IDictionary<string, string> PropertyFieldNamesAndValues { get; set; }


    public string GetValue(string propertyOrFieldName)
    {
        bool isKnown = PropertyFieldNamesAndValues.TryGetValue(propertyOrFieldName, out string value);
        if (isKnown)
            return value;
        return null;
    }

    // if you want to know all informations about the property or field like type
    public MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(string propertyOrFieldName)
    {
        MemberInfo memberInfo = PropertiesAndFields.Keys.FirstOrDefault(mi => mi.Name == propertyOrFieldName);
        return memberInfo;
    }
}
```

Now you need a converter method:

```
public static StringType ConvertSomeClassToString(Object instance)
{
    BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public; // maybe as parameter, cgange accordingly
    Type t = instance.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties(bindingFlags);
    FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(bindingFlags);
    var propertyMemberValues = properties.Select(p => new { Member = (MemberInfo) p, Value = p.GetValue(instance) });
    var fieldMemberValues = fields.Select(f => new { Member = (MemberInfo) f, Value = f.GetValue(instance) });

    Dictionary<MemberInfo, string> dict = propertyMemberValues
        .Concat(fieldMemberValues)
        .ToDictionary(m => m.Member, m => m.Value?.ToString());
    return new StringType(dict);
}
```

This converts any type instance to `StringType`. Here's a sample:

```
var list = new List<SomeClass>() { new SomeClass { Name = "foo", Cd = 4711 } };
Converter<Object, StringType> converter = ConvertSomeClassToString;
List<StringType> stringItemList = list.ConvertAll(converter);
StringType st = stringItemList.First();
string valueOfCD = st.GetValue("Cd"); // "4711"
```